# Does NodeJS have any performance demerits or significant overhead in comparison to pure V8?

Tags: c++, node.js, embed, v8, embedded-v8

The application I'm developing runs on a desktop environment. On the back-end, it runs C++. The front end is user-modifiable and written in JavaScript that uses some exposed classes/functions from the C++.

I'm currently trying to determine whether the application should simply run v8 alone in order to run the JavaScript code, or if it should "upgrade" to using NodeJS. The benefit to upgrading would be access to a plethora of Node modules, both built-in and third party for users to rely upon. However, I am concerned that the performance of the JavaScript may be hindered due to the extra baggage that Node would bring with it.

Perhaps it would be better to implement by own versions of the most common Node modules in the C++ back-end and expose them to the JS? Or are they going to have irrelevant/no performance differences whatsoever?

Comment: Javascript is run by V8 in both Chrome and node.js.  It's unclear where you think these performance degradations would be coming from or why you even think this is something to be concerned about.  Further, it's not a trivial project to make a new environment to run V8 in and to recreate a bunch of node.js modules so even if you found some aspect of node.js that caused you problems, I think you'd rather fork it and modify than recreate from scratch.

Comment: @jfriend00 Does Node not also include a ton of other features and functions such as libuv, require, extra libraries, etc? The JavaScript doesn't just go straight into v8.

Comment: Well, once Javascript is executing, it's just V8 executing it.  libuv is a cross platform library to allow features to be designed one that will work multiple operating systems.  It doesn't come into play for actually executing Javascript instructions.  It does help implement timers, an event loop, file system access, etc..., all of which you will presumably need.  But, just because a platform has lots of features does not say anything about how it performs when running Javascript.  They are largely two separate things.

Comment: For example, the addition of the `fs` module to the environment doesn't have anything to do with how fast a Javascript loop is executed.  You don't state anything about what exact performance you're concerned about so we can't really comment any more specifically.  "performance" as a word is a massively broad word in this situation.

Comment: All right, I see! Thanks for explaining, I apologize for the vagueness of the question provided. I shall go through with developing with Node in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building against NodeJS will not incur a significant performance penalty. It might, however, introduce a maintainability penalty and a security penalty. NodeJS may have many features that you are not using in your application. It might have features that you actually don't want your Javascript authors to have access to. Are you running in a high security environment? You might want to limit your Javascript authors' access to the filesystem and to the network. If you are running third party untrusted code within your application, and your application is running on a separate third party's system, you definitely have security implications to think about. In this case, building directly against V8 would be a better choice.

Comment: Something important to add on here is that Node.js uses libuv, which is (in very simplified terms) a big while loop. This is because in Node.js, JavaScript drives execution. If you call into JS-land more than your JS calls into C++ land you should be wary of this fact.